# gnome terminal moving through folders

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, shell

I was wondering if there was a way to navigate back to the previous folder after a 'cd'.

e.g.

```
~/ cd /home/
~/ cd /usr/local/
~/ want should I write here to return to the home dir (not 'cd /home' ^^)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any particular shell?

Comment: I am using the standard gnome-terminal that comes with ubuntu 11.04 (not Unity)

Comment: gnome-terminal is not a shell.

Comment: I didn't say that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using bash or some similar shell you can use `cd -` to return to the previous working directory.

```
[ignacio@localhost ~]$ cd bin/
[ignacio@localhost bin]$ cd -
/home/ignacio
[ignacio@localhost ~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

The pushd/popd utilities keep a stack of the directories that you have visited.

```
[arcege]:~/Documents> pushd /usr/local
/usr/local ~/Documents
[arcege]:/usr/local> pushd /tmp
/tmp /usr/local ~/Documents
[arcege]:/tmp> dirs
/tmp /usr/local ~/Documents
[arcege]:/tmp> popd
/usr/local ~/Documents
[arcege]:/usr/local> popd
~/Documents
[arcege]:~/Documents>
```

The downside is that you need to remember to use `pushd` instead of `cd`.